# HTML5 history pushState relative URLs/queries/hash tags?

Tags: html, browser-history, html5-history

I'm using Ajax content loading and pushStates for a more responsive interface, but I've ran into a problem.

When navigating through the website everything works fine, the content get's loaded and the URL is changed to whatever I choose `history.pushState({'url':newUrl},"", newUrl);`

I have a lot of relative links on my page, especially GET parameters such as `<a href="?view=more">..</a>`. In a normal environment the `?view=more` part gets appended to the working URL and the pages loads what's needed.

My problem is that when using these URLs, it appends `?view=more` to the first page URL that was "hard" loaded, so when navigating throughout the website the GET parameters get only appended to the first loaded page..  The same thing goes with hashtags. If I have a link `<a href="#details">..</a>` I can see that my browser appends the hashtag to the first loaded page URL.

How do I make these types of URLs respond the current active URL?..

Comment: What does `newUrl` look like? And the bit of HTML where the link(s) are in?

Comment: @putvande - `newUrl` is a relative URL such as `/someLink` or `/some/link`